# Returning a method back a previous method without resetting variables etc

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a program wherein when you are done with one menu, you click on "Previous Menu" and it should take you back to another menu.  I'm having an issue getting return to function such that after choosing something within the menu, it will still return to the previous menu as opposed to just returning you the same menu you're on.

```
void doElection() {

    JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    Object[] mainValues = { "Voter", "Administrator", "Exit" };
    String mainfirst = "Voter";

//      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  count); // DEBUG 
//      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, voter.voterssn); // DEBUG

    Object mainMenu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Main Menu", "2062 Voting", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, mainValues, mainfirst);

    if(mainMenu == null || mainMenu.equals("Exit")) {

        System.exit(1);

    }

    while(!(mainMenu == null || mainMenu.equals("Exit"))) {

        if(mainMenu.equals("Voter")) {

            votermenu();

        } //end if


        adminValidate(mainMenu);

    }
```

The second method:

```
void votermenu() {

    Object[] votemenval = {"Register to Vote", "Vote", "Previous Menu"};

    String votemenfirst = "Register to Vote";

    Object votermenu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Voter Menu", "2062 Voting", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, votemenval, votemenfirst);

    if(votermenu.equals("Previous Menu") || votermenu.equals(null)) {
        return;
    }

    voteButtons(votermenu);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object mainMenu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Main Menu", "2062 Voting", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, mainValues, mainfirst);` only displays the main menu once, since it is not in any loop. You need to move it to inside the loop, and then rejig the rest of the code to fit around that. You might want to consider using a `do..while` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you.  Took some finagling, but yeah it works correctly now. :)